# How to setup Database connection using php coding and where to save that file?

Tags: php

I am having some problems with php coding i have written php coding correct but it is not working,it is giving an error that "The Object not found" in browser.

Hey guyz please help me i am stuck on this and tried every possible thing to make this coding work.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please post your code so i can help you

Comment: Here's the coding`<?php
$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

$databasename = "practice";

$dbConnected = mysql_connect($db'hostname',$db'username',$db'password');

$dbSelected = mysql_select_db($db['databasename'],$dbConnected);


if ($dbConnected) {
 echo "MySQL connected OK<br /><br />";

 if ($dbSelected) {
  echo "DB connected OK<br /><br />";
 } else {
  echo "DB connection FAILED<br /><br />";
 }  
} else {
 echo "MySQL connection FAILED<br /><br />";
}

?>

Answer (score 0):

First php is not supported by itself in browser, you need a server to run php,you can use a localhost server like wamp, create DB in phpMyAdmin panel with the desired username and password then you can connect to it from your classes.

$this->host="localhost";
    $this->username="root";
    $this->password="";
    $this->database="dbname";
$con=mysql_connect($this->host,$this->username,$this->password) or die(mysql_error());
$res=mysql_select_db($this->database,$con)or die(mysql_error());

Answer (score -1):

you can save the file in any folder but it is advisable for u to save it in where all your files are kept for a quick reference.
below is php code for setting up database:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("host","user","password") or die(mysqli_error());
mysqli_select_db($con,"yourdatabasename");
```

Note:
host=localhost(if wamp or xampp is used) or your domain name(like www.google.com)
You can save dis php file with any name e.g config.php.
user= username of your database used in your phpmyadmin. likewise your password.
If you are using wamp or xampp, use dis format:
$con=mysqli_connect("locahost","root","") or die(mysqli_error());